# Python regex pattern for datetime

Tags: python, regex

How to write regular expression that matches both datetime format `2015-01-13T16:12:04.000Z` and date format `6/19/14`?

Comment: You appear to have this confused with a regex-writing service; it really isn't. Also, you want `strptime`, not a regular expression.

Answer (score 2):

You can parse dates like this:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
d = parse("2015-01-13T16:12:04.000Z")
```

Now `d` is a `datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 13, 16, 12, 4, tzinfo=tzutc())`. This can be printed like

```
import datetime
print("{d.month}/{d.day}/{d.year}".format(d=datetime.datetime.now()))
```